# Correlation between two equation that involves summing a series of number

Tags: arithmetic

Firstly, I apologize as I don't have strong mathematical background, hence this basic questions comes in this forum.

Say I have a equations as below:

$E_i = x_i/y_i$

$A = (E_1 + E_2 + E_3 + ... +E_n)/n$

$B = (x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_n)/(y_1+y_2+y_3+...+y_n)$

**Is there any figure ($z$) that I can multiply with A to create: $Az = B$ ?**

I have no clue on how to start, since n isn't specified and can be any integer number. Any help will be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Are you meaning $E_i=\frac{x_i}{y_i}$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes that's correct. Thanks for pointing the errors.

Comment: Do it with $n=3$ to see what you obtain. The pattern is more that clear.

Comment: Try to find two different sets of numbers that give the same $B$ but different values of $A$.